# Recursion Problem ...Sierpinskis Triangle

Tags: python, recursion

I am working on the sierpinskis triangle and can’t seem to move beyond the first two iterations since we getting this  error:

```
8.py", line 43, in drawTriangle
    t.setposition(x,y)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'setposition'
```

why is it reading ‘t’ as a float?

Below is the code we have so far...

```
def drawFractal(t, order, size):
    """The base case is just a rightside-up triangle"""                  
    t.forward(size)   
    t.left(120)                 
    t.forward(size)  
    t.left(120)               
    t.forward(size)    
    t.left(120)
    (x, y) = t.position()
    drawTriangle(x,y,order-1,t,size/2)
    """we must stop drawing so that we can cross from one stored point
    in the triangle to another on the other side"""
##    t.penup()
##    t.goto(x,y)
##    t.pendown()

#create a helper function
def drawTriangle(x,y,order,t, size):
    #we need to store the 3 separate (x,y) coordinate values for each
    #new triangle
    if order < 0: #not entirely sure about this number
        return 
    else:
        #step 1: draw upside down triangle
        #set position to x,y (automatically stored with each iteration)
        t.setposition(x,y)
        #^this code isn't working for some reason (t seems to be a float?)
        #setting (x,y) = to the moethod doesn't help

        t.forward(size)
        (x2, y2) = t.position()
        t.left(60)                 
        t.forward(size)  
        t.left(120)               
        t.forward(size)
        (x3, y3)=t.position()
        t.left(120)
        t.forward(size)

        #step 2: recursion - call drawTriangle 3x
        drawTriangle(x,y, order-1, size/2, t)
        drawTriangle(x2,y2, order-1, size/2, t)
        drawTriangle(x3,y3, order-1, size/2, t)
```

Comment: Do you have the code where you are instantiating the `t` object? It looks like whatever you are making is a float, not an object (like Python expects).

Comment: The parameters of `drawTriangle` are `(x,y,order,t, size)`, but you call it at the end with a different order `(x,y, order-1, size/2, t)`

Comment: You reversed the position of the `size` and `t` arguments to the recursive calls. Use `drawTriangle(x, y, order - 1, t, size/2)`, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems in end of your function your order of arguments in last calls are incorrect. replace last lines of `drawTriangle` function with these lines :

```
def drawTriangle(x,y,order,t, size):
    ....
    drawTriangle(x,y, order-1, t, size/2)
    drawTriangle(x2,y2, order-1, t, size/2)
    drawTriangle(x3,y3, order-1, t, size/2)
```